# Realloc invalid pointer

Tags: pointers, memory, malloc, realloc, assertion

I'm writing a code for calculate AES by CUDA but I have some problems with realloc() on the CPU side of the code.
When I read the data from the disk I need to encrypt I use this piece of code:

```
puint4 * cipher_block;
u32 posizione = 0;
FILE * inputFile = fopen("input.in","rb");
while(!feof(inputFile)){
    if((cipher_block = (puint4 *)realloc(cipher_block,sizeof(puint4)*(posizione+1))) == NULL){
       printf("\nERROR\n");
    }
    //read data
    .....
    posizione++;
}//end while
```

It works fine until I add (following) another piece of code which I use for allocate the memory on the GPU:

```
puint4 * round_key_GPU;
puint4 * cipher_block_GPU;

cudaMalloc((void**)&round_key_GPU,sizeof(puint4)*11);
cudaMalloc((void**)&cipher_block_GPU,sizeof(puint4)*(posizione+1));

//other instructions
....

/* Libero le risorse */
cudaFree(round_key_GPU);
cudaFree(cipher_block_GPU);
free(round_key_GPU);
free(cipher_block_GPU);
free(cipher_block);
free(round_key);
```

When I add this piece of code the realloc() instruction returns the error:

```
*** Error in `./test.x': realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000402338 ***
```

And if I delete

```
free(round_key_GPU);
free(cipher_block_GPU);
```

It return the error:

```
test.x: malloc.c:2842: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (_rtld_global_ro._dl_pagesize - 1)) == 0' failed.
```

So I think that maybe the round_key_GPU and cipher_block_GPU pointer have been allocated before the while loop finish to read all the data and then the realloc() overwrite the memory space of the pointers. What do you think? If is this the case how can i read the data from the disk without know how much data i have to read?

(P.S. puint4 is a typedef structure with 4 unsigned int, like uint4)

Thank!
Davide

Comment: Where do you initialise cipher_block?

Comment: Function `realloc` takes as input a pointer to a memory segment that was allocated either by function `malloc` or by function `realloc`. Function `cudaMalloc` is neither one of those two.

Comment: You are righ guys! I forgot to inizialized the pointers.. I was confused by the fact that without some istructions the code worked.
Thank you very much!